# How to pass file names with spaces to Perl drop target in Windows

Tags: windows, perl

I have set up Strawberry Perl pl scripts as drop target using Michael's answer [How do I make my Perl scripts act like normal programs on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows)

(I wrote small script for this, because after Strawberry Perl upgrade re-registration is required: https://gist.github.com/Vlado-99/b437cc6cc2ea764b1f74d4f2b8404102).

If I drop "simple" file name, like "report.txt", my script receives "report.txt".

But if I drop long file name, like "report for 2020-01 (sorted).txt", my scripts gets

```
ARGV[0]='report'
ARGV[1]='for'
ARGV[2]='2020-01'
ARGV[3]='(sorted).txt'
```

and if I drop name like "C:\PlexLibrary\Chisum (1970)\Chisum(1970).mp4", script gets

```
ARGV[0]='C:\PLEXLI~1\Chisum'
ARGV[1]='(1970)\Chisum(1970).mp4'
```

How to:

1. Prevent filenames broken to more parts,
2. Prevent use of short DOS 8.3 names instead of Windows long names?

My filesystem is NTFS, Windows is 64-bit Windows 7 Professional, Perl is

```
C:\>perl --version

This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Copyright 1987-2020, Larry Wall
```

Comment: Possible workaroud with cmd wrapper: see ijprest's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705851/how-do-i-create-drag-and-drop-strawberry-perl-programs

Comment: I am testing this on Windows 10: If I run the script `RegisterStrawberryPerlAsDropTarget.cmd` from CMD as admin, I get *"Please run this script with administrative/elevated permissions."*

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I missed to say, my Windows is 7, not 10. I have no 10, so I wrote script for 7 only (there are some differences in Michael's description, if I remember). Script warns if you forget to run it elevated - use Run as Administrator, please.